# Translate json root element jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I am using jackson 1.9 and use its `ObjectMapper` class for serializing and deserializing my content. So I am using a **PropertyNamingStrategy** which converts all my keys in a specific form during serializing and reverse backduring deserializing.

```
public class LongNameShortNameNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {

        System.out.println("Translate: " + propertyName);
        String shortName = null, longName = null;
    longName = LongNameShortNames.getLongName(propertyName);

        if (longName != null){
            return longName;
        }

        shortName = LongNameShortNames.getShortName(propertyName);
        if (shortName != null){
            return shortName;
        }

        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

However this leads to give me json like:

OBJECT MAPPER:---> JSON STRING:

```
{
  "ContentInstance" : {
    "st" : 1,
    "cs" : 10,
    "con" : "Sid"
  }
```

So my `NamingStrategy` is not applied on the json root element. It's name is not converted to a short name during serialization.

How can I apply a similar serializing and de-serializing strategy for my root element too ??